# Unity Pathfinding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I have problem with my multiplayer game!

The game has monster that has 3 phases

WONDER: in this phase the monster walks normally in the map, but if he gets too close to player or gets shot at --> phase RAGE

RAGE:In rage mode the monster will get close to the player and will attack (after dealing x amount of damage to player or getting shot at 5-7 times) --> phase SCARE

SCARED: in scared mode monster will run away from players and after time he will ho into Wonder phase

But the problem is I don't know what pathfinding method I should use (I want cleanest possible) and I also don't know how exactly make the phases

Comment: Unity has built-in pathfinding.  Alternatively you could look at the famous _steering behaviours_ by Craig Reynolds

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alU04hvz6L4
You should look for A* pathfinding. And to make phases, try making first one phase and once you figure out how to implement that, create the other ones. Focus on one thing at a time.